# Application login fails while running JMeter proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter

my test app is opencart, I am unable to record login scenario for open cart. The scenario is, if i provide a username/password while proxy recording is off, works fine. But when i've started recording and providing the username/password will not work

The response data says

> **Notice**: Undefined index: email in **D:\Program
>   Files\wamp\www\opencart\catalog\controller\account\login.php** on
>   line **201****Notice**: Undefined index: password in
>   **D:\Program
>   Files\wamp\www\opencart\catalog\controller\account\login.php** on
>   line **201****Notice**: Undefined index: email in **D:\Program
>   Files\wamp\www\opencart\catalog\controller\account\login.php** on
>   line **205**

another error message displayed is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected method: 
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:252)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1088)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:211)
```

Apart from that other recording is working fine, clicking links navigating to another page all works fine

Answer (score 0):

Provide Http sampler settings type  as HttpClient3.1 in proxy

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing seems to come from an unexpected HTTP Method used.
It seems to be none of:

- POST
- PUT
- HEAD
- TRACE
- OPTIONS
- DELETE
- GET
- PATCH

Can you give more details on it ?

Comment: In http proxy server, if i use any type value other than HttpcClient3.1, i got this error message. The application i used is the cart application i downloaded from opencart.org and i use wamp under win xp.

Comment: Which JMeter version are you using ?